# Getting grid view on button click event

Tags: asp.net

Hello on page load we get two buttons while clicking on 1st button one grid view and while clicking on 2nd grid view,2grid views put in 2 DIV's.there is lot of records so need paging requirement and have to convert each page in to Document or pdf by exporting my code

Any useful links or perfect code to implement in my project

Comment: Not to be rude, but if you haven't tried anything on your part and all you have to say is that you need a link, why don't you do the googling yourself instead of asking the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx

Comment: need more refernces to get paging in grid view 1st page is showing data but clicking on 2nd page it not showing anything

Comment: Posting the relevant piece of your code here that you are using for paging will definitely help